How to bind to realtime updates in multiple Firestore queries aggregated into a single reactive array
I would like to combine the results of several Firestore queries into a single array of documents to which I can bind to realtime updates like for a simple query.
I am using Vuefire to simplify "using" the data in Vue so ideally I'd like a way of sending an array of queries to Vuefire, but it doesn't support that, only single query, collection or document.
I have looked at doing what Vuefire does under the hood, i.e. handling the onSnapshot events, and I think I can probably write a multi-query version which splices into an aggregated array using offsets for each query's subset, but it's got complicated and I am hoping for a simpler solution.
Why do I want to do this?
Normally, in this specific app, I query Firestore from the web SDK and therefore can easily bind the data to the UI and receive instant updates to changes. However I am now using one Firestore feature which is not available in the web SDK (vector search queries) and so I have written a Firebase Function which returns a set of documents (or just IDs). I want to be able to bind to this set of documents while the user interacts with them (like the other collections), so I wrote a query which re-selects these documents in the web SDK by their IDs. However there's another limitation which is the 30-document max for a "where in" clause, which means I can only select 30 documents by-ID in one query. I have solved this in the past simply by batching the query into 30 document chunks, iterating and appending to an aggregate array of doc.data(). This is fine for static data, but I want to bind to these Firestore documents - ideally to send the result of this manually aggregated set of queries into the useCollection of Vuex.
I think this is similar to this question which is addressing similar limitations: Listening for realtime updates of multiple queries with Firestore and geohashing
My "normal" way of selecting a list of documents by-id would be like this:
export async function listDocumentsByIds(collectionPath: string, ids: string[]): Promise<object[]> {
  const items:object[] = []

  const batches = slices(ids, FIRESTORE_ID_QUERY_LIMIT)
  for (const batch of batches) {
    const q = query(collection(db, collectionPath), where(documentId(), 'in', batch))
    await getDocs(q).forEach(qds => items.push({id: qds.id, ...qds.data()}))
  }
  return items
}

but as you can see I've done doc.data() and so there's no ability to subscribe to doc changes.
So I was thinking to make a version of this which returns an array of chunk queries which can be subscribed to like:
export async function queryDocumentsByIds(collectionPath: string, ids: string[]): Promise<Query[]> {
  const queries:Query[] = []

  const batches = slices(ids, FIRESTORE_ID_QUERY_LIMIT)
  for (const batch of batches) {
    const q = query(collection(db, collectionPath), where(documentId(), 'in', batch))
      queries.push(q)
  }

  return queries
}

ideally I'd want to send the Query[] to Vuefire and get a single Ref<doc[]> with all the chunks appended togeteher (wishful thinking).
So I was thinking of appending the data myself into a Ref<doc[]> containing an array of documents (chunks) and then subscribing to the changes in each Query, and finding the documents in the array via an array index offset which would be like i + c * 30 (chunk size).
Something like this (unfinished - need to figure out all the index offsets)
export async function useQueryArray(collectionPath: string, ids: string[]){
  const multiRef = ref([])
  const queries:Query[] = await queryDocumentsByIds(collectionPath, ids)

  // listen to all changes on all queries, and merge the changes into our union data ref
  for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    const q = queries[i]
    const offset = i * FIRESTORE_ID_QUERY_LIMIT
    
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData, DocumentData>) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        const { newIndex, oldIndex, doc, type } = change
        if (type === 'added') {
          multiRef.value.splice(newIndex, 0, doc.data())
        }
        else if (type === 'modified') {
          multiRef.value.splice(oldIndex, 1)
          multiRef.value.splice(newIndex, 0, doc.data())
        }
        else if (type === 'removed') {
          multiRef.value.splice(oldIndex, 1)
        }
      })
    }, onErrorHandler)
  }
}

but before I try to finish this manually, I was wondering if there was a simpler way to combine query "pages" reactively - considering I only had to split the pages due to limitations in the SDKs.

I solved this at the "Vue level" rather than in Firestore or Vuefire, after realising that this is a general case of needing an reactive aggregate array (i.e. an array flattened from several other arrays which are all reactive refs) and that can be done using a computed property.
The only complication was that in this case, the vector distance returned from my Firebase Function was not present in the collections re-fetched via the later direct Firestore queries - which required a hash/lookup and also a sort inside the computed function while appending the chunks (of 30 IDs).
In summary the process is (simplified):
const ids: string[] = [] // doc ids for re-fetching
const distances: {id:string, distance:number}[] = [] // map to reinstate KNN distances
let chunks = ref([]) // array of useCollection refs

// Call the Function which does the vector search back-end
const similar = await getSimilar(docId, k)

// make lookup table of distances, and list of IDs
similar.forEach(s => {
      ids.push(s.id)
      distances.push({id:s.id, distance:s.distance})
    })

// re-fetch the docs locally to get several VueFire collections (of max 30 IDs)
const queries = await queryDocumentsByIds(collectionPath, ids)
// make all queries into Vuefire reactive collections
chunks.value = queries.map(q => useCollection(q))

// compute finalList - the reactive Firestore collection of all chunks
// add the vector distance back in from the map
const finalList = computed(() => {
  return chunks.value.reduce((refs, ref) => {
    ref.value.forEach(r => {
      const distmap = distances.find(d => d.id === r.id)
      refs.push({ ...r, distance: distmap?.distance })
    })
    return refs
  }, [])
    .sort((r1, r2) => r1.distance - r2.distance)
})

// I can now use `finalList` as a single array in my Vue paginated table 
// and it receives Firestore updates as it if was from a single Vuefire query.

This isn't as complicated as replicating the Vuefire binding.
